# Converting a blank input to a zero?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using eclipse for an android app and the users input a value that is the used in a formula. When they dont enter the value, it will error out so i want any blank inputs to be changed to zeros. heres the code i have:

```
EditText numAA=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.numAAAn);
Double num1=Double.parseDouble(numAA.getText().toString());
if ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.numAAAn) == null) {
    numAA=0;
}
```

And it has a error on the 0 that says "type mismatch: cannot convert from int to edittext" so im assuming it wants it converted but im not sure how. I tired adding quotes around the 0 but that didnt work either.

Comment: you have to set value of `EditText` like numAA.setText("0").

Answer (score 2):

Before parsing the double, check if `numAA` is empty or null. If it is then assign default value.

This is my solution:

```
Double num1 = 0.0; // Default value..
EditText numAA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numAAAn);

if (numAA.getText() != null && numAA.length() != 0) {
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(numAA.getText().toString());
} else {
    numAA.setText("0");
}
```

You can create a separate function to perform this operation. Like:

```
public Double parseInput(Double defaultValue, EditText editText) {
    if (editText.getText() != null && editText.length() != 0) {
        return Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
    } else {
        editText.setText("0");
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

And from the caller, use it like:

```
Double num1 = parseInput(0.0, (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numAAAn));
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer as it correctly checks if the EditText is null before using it. This could be improved by changing the if statement to: if (numAA != null) which would reduce the overhead of having to findViewById() and cast twice.

Comment: ok. i have like 20 inputs. Is there a way to include all of those inputs into one if statement or should i make 20 separate statements?

Comment: @user3688499 You can create a separate function to do this validation. If all are expected to be `Double` then it is very easy.

Comment: doing this without the separate function still force closes the app in the emulator when the spot is left blank

Comment: Check for the input length as well `editText.length() != 0`. I have updated the code to include this condition. Add LOG statements as well to know the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter=0;
EditText numAA=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.numAAAn);
Double num1=Double.parseDouble(numAA.getText().toString());
if ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.numAAAn) == null) {
    numAA.setText(counter+"");
}
```

try this:

Comment: this code will throw a NPE if numAA is null, as the null check is performed after calling a method on numAA

Comment: ok. i have like 20 inputs. Is there a way to include all of those inputs into one if statement or should i make 20 separate statements?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
EditText numAA=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.numAAAn);
    if (numAA.length()==0) {
        numAA.setText("0");//or if you want nothing to show in the edittext, leave this one blank
    } else {
        Double num1=Double.parseDouble(numAA.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

The `length()` method checks the length of the string within an edittext.

Comment: this gives an error that says edittext and int are not compatable

Comment: You need to take care of the scope of `num1` variable as well.